# Is there a way to interrupt epoll_wait when the serial port finished sending data in output buffer and output buffer is emty?

Tags: c++, linux

I'm making a kind of device driver with queue of commands. I need to know when the data packet, that I sent to serial port by calling `::write()`, is actually was completely sent by serial port (serial port can be very slow).

Is there any way to interrupt `epoll_wait()` when it happens? The only way I see now is to interrupt `epoll_wait()` after some timeout (actually, I can calculate timeout knowing baud rate and packet length), and check free space of the serial port's output buffer. But but maybe there's more elegant solution?

Comment: well write is not poll, and write is synchronous...  must be missing something..

Comment: show us what you tried

Comment: If you want to know when the buffer is ready for you to write more data, you can wait for EPOLLOUT event. That's not the same as the buffer being empty, though. Why do you need to know when it's empty?